# How to implement Swift-like enums with associated values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, swift, data-structures, enums, language-design

The Swift language has a fantastic enum support. Not only can one define a standard enum with cases, but cases can have optional values "associated to them."

For example, taken from the Swift docs:

```
enum Barcode {
    case UPCA(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case QRCode(String)
    case Other
}
```

Such that one could create a Barcode enum by passing in a value, like so:

`var productBarcode = Barcode.UPCA(8, 85909, 51226, 3)`

and also `switch` on `productBarcode` at a later date to retrieve the associated value (a tuple of `int`s).

---

I have been trying to implement this kind of `enum` system in JavaScript (ES5, in particular), but am hitting a wall. What is the best way to structure an enum system, especially one with associated values?

Comment: Man, I've been having trouble doing the same thing. I love them in Swift, but need them in JavaScript!

Comment: Enum in Swift is *very sexy*. For example, they are useful in [Redux actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's notr exactly the way enums work in most languages i know. Usually they are more like a way to type a value as one of these states. Like selecting one value out of a set of possible values. And to ensure type-safety in doing this, unlike with plain integers.

What you posted in your code, I would call a plain Object with factory-methods.

Since they are not supported that way by the language you have to implement them in a way that fit's your needs as good as possible. So sum up what behaviour you expect.

In the mean time a Implementation based on the descriptions i've found on swift enums. hope it comes close to what you expect:

```
var odp = {
    ENUMERABLE: 4,

    //two helper with Object.defineProperty.
    value: function(obj, prop, v, flags){
        this.configurable = Boolean(flags & odp.CONFIGURABLE);
        this.writable = Boolean(flags & odp.WRITABLE);
        this.enumerable = Boolean(flags & odp.ENUMERABLE);
        this.value = v;
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, this);
        this.value = null;  //v may be a function or an object: remove the reference
        return obj;
    }.bind({    //caching the basic definition
        value: null, 
        configurable: false, 
        writable: false, 
        enumerable: false 
    }),

    accessor: function(obj, prop, getter, setter){
        this.get = getter || undefined;
        this.set = setter || undefined;
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, this);
        this.get = null;
        this.set = null;
        return obj;
    }.bind({ get: null, set: null })
}
//make these values immutable
odp.value(odp, "CONFIGURABLE", 1, odp.ENUMERABLE);
odp.value(odp, "WRITABLE", 2, odp.ENUMERABLE);
odp.value(odp, "ENUMERABLE", 4, odp.ENUMERABLE);



//Policy: 
//1. I don't f*** care wether the keys on the definition are own or inherited keys.
//since you pass them to me, I suppose you want me to process them.

//2. If i find some undefined-value i ignore it, as if it wasn't there.
//use null to represent some "empty" value

//name and extendProto are optional
function Enum(name, description, extendProto){
    var n = name, d = description, xp=extendProto;
    if(n && typeof n === "object") xp=d, d = n, n = null;
    var xpf = typeof xp === "function" && xp;
    var xpo = typeof xp === "object" && xp;

    function type(){ 
        throw new Error("enums are not supposed to be created manually"); 
    }

    //abusing filter() as forEach()
    //removing the keys that are undefined in the same step.
    var keys = Object.keys(d).filter(function(key){
        var val = d[key];
        if(val === undefined) return false;
        var proto = Object.create(type.prototype);

        //your chance to extend the particular prototype with further properties
        //like adding the prototype-methods of some other type
        var props = xpf || xpo && xpo[key];
        if(typeof props === "function") 
            props = props.call(type, proto, key, val);

        if(props && typeof props === "object" && props !== proto && props !== val){
            var flags = odp.CONFIGURABLE+odp.WRITABLE;
            for(var k in props) props[k]===undefined || odp.value(proto, k, props[k], flags);
            if("length" in props) odp.value(props, "length", props.length, flags);
        }

        if(typeof val === "function"){
            //a factory and typedefinition at the same type
            //call this function to create a new object of the type of this enum
            //and of the type of this function at the same time
            type[key] = function(){
                var me = Object.create(proto);
                var props = val.apply(me, arguments);
                if(props && typeof props === "object" && props !== me){
                    for(var k in props) props[k]===undefined || odp.value(me, k, props[k], odp.ENUMERABLE);
                    if("length" in props) odp.value(me, "length", props.length);
                }
                return me;
            }
            //fix the fn.length-property for this factory
            odp.value(type[key], "length", val.length, odp.CONFIGURABLE);

            //change the name of this factory
            odp.value(type[key], "name", (n||"enum")+"{ "+key+" }" || key, odp.CONFIGURABLE);

            type[key].prototype = proto;
            odp.value(proto, "constructor", type[key], odp.CONFIGURABLE);

        }else if(val && typeof val === "object"){
            for(var k in val) val[k] === undefined || odp.value(proto, k, val[k]);
            if("length" in val) odp.value(proto, "length", val.length);
            type[key] = proto;

        }else{
            //an object of the type of this enum that wraps the primitive
            //a bit like the String or Number or Boolean Classes

            //so remember, when dealing with this kind of values, 
            //you don't deal with actual primitives
            odp.value(proto, "valueOf", function(){ return val; });     
            type[key] = proto;

        }

        return true;
    });

    odp.value(type, "name", n || "enum[ " + keys.join(", ") + " ]", odp.CONFIGURABLE);
    Object.freeze(type);

    return type;
}
```

Beware, this code may need some further modification. Examples:

**Factories**

```
function uint(v){ return v>>>0 }

var Barcode = Enum("Barcode", {
    QRCode: function(string){
        //this refers to an object of both types, Barcode and Barcode.QRCode
        //aou can modify it as you wish
        odp.value(this, "valueOf", function(){ return string }, true);
    },

    UPCA: function(a,b,c,d){
        //you can also return an object with the properties you want to add
        //and Arrays, ...
        return [
            uint(a), 
            uint(b), 
            uint(c), 
            uint(d)
        ];
        //but beware, this doesn't add the Array.prototype-methods!!!

        //event this would work, and be processed like an Array
        return arguments;
    },

    Other: function(properties){ 
        return properties;  //some sugar
    }
});

var productBarcode = Barcode.UPCA(8, 85909, 51226, 3);
console.log("productBarcode is Barcode:", productBarcode instanceof Barcode);   //true
console.log("productBarcode is Barcode.UPCA:", productBarcode instanceof Barcode.UPCA); //true

console.log("productBarcode is Barcode.Other:", productBarcode instanceof Barcode.Other);   //false

console.log("accessing values: ", productBarcode[0], productBarcode[1], productBarcode[2], productBarcode[3], productBarcode.length);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(productBarcode, function(value, index){
    console.log("index:", index, "  value:", value);
});
```

**Objects and Primitives**

```
var indices = Enum({
    lo: { from: 0, to: 13 },
    hi: { from: 14, to: 42 },

    avg: 7
});

var lo = indices.lo;
console.log("lo is a valid index", lo instanceof indices);
console.log("lo is indices.lo", lo === indices.lo); 
//indices.lo always references the same Object
//no function-call, no getter!

var avg = indices.avg;  //beware, this is no primitive, it is wrapped

console.log("avg is a valid index", avg instanceof indices);
console.log("comparison against primitives:");
console.log(" - typesafe", avg === 7);  //false, since avg is wrapped!!!
console.log(" - loose", avg == 7);  //true
console.log(" - typecast+typesafe", Number(avg) === 7); //true

//possible usage like it was a primitive.
for(var i=lo.from; i<lo.to; ++i){
    console.log(i, i == avg);   //take a look at the first output ;)
}

//but if you want to use some of the prototype methods 
//(like the correct toString()-method on Numbers, or substr on Strings)
//make sure that you have a proper primitive!

var out = avg.toFixed(3);
//will fail since this object doesn't provide the prototype-methods of Number

//+avg does the same as Number(avg)
var out = (+avg).toFixed(3);    //will succeed
```

**Identity**

```
var def = { foo: 42 };

var obj = Enum({
    a: 13,
    b: 13,
    c: 13,

    obj1: def,
    obj2: def
});

//although all three have/represent the same value, they ain't the same
var v = obj.a;
console.log("testing a", v === obj.a, v === obj.b, v===obj.c);  //true, false, false

var v = obj.b;
console.log("testing a", v === obj.a, v === obj.b, v===obj.c);  //false, true, false

var v = obj.c;
console.log("testing a", v === obj.a, v === obj.b, v===obj.c);  //false, false, true


console.log("comparing objects", obj.obj1 === obj.obj2);    //false
console.log("comparing property foo", obj.obj1.foo === obj.obj2.foo);   //true

//same for the values provided by the factory-functions:
console.log("compare two calls with the same args:");
console.log("Barcode.Other() === Barcode.Other()", Barcode.Other() === Barcode.Other());
//will fail, since the factory doesn't cache, 
//every call creates a new Object instance.
//if you need to check wether they are equal, write a function that does that.
```

**extendProto**

```
//your chance to extend the prototype of each subordinated entry in the enum
//maybe you want to add some method from some other prototype 
//like String.prototype or iterator-methods, or a method for equality-checking, ...

var Barcode = Enum("Barcode", {/* factories */}, function(proto, key, value){
    var _barcode = this;    
    //so you can access the enum in closures, without the need for a "global" variable.
    //but if you mess around with this, you are the one to debug the Errors you produce.

    //this function is executed right after the prototpe-object for this enum-entry is created
    //and before any further modification.
    //neither this particular entry, nor the enum itself are done yet, so don't mess around with them.

    //the only purpose of this method is to provide you a hook 
    //to add further properties to the proto-object

    //aou can also return an object with properties to add to the proto-object.
    //these properties will be added as configurable and writable but not enumerable.
    //and no getter or setter. If you need more control, feel free to modify proto on you own.
    return {
        isBarcode: function(){
            return this instanceof _barcode;
        }
    }
});

//OR you can define it for every single property, 
//so you don't have to switch on the different properties in one huge function
var Barcode = Enum("Barcode", {/* factories */}, {
    "UPCA": function(proto, key, value){
        //same behaviour as the universal function
        //but will be executed only for the proto of UPCA

        var _barcode = this;    //aka Barcode in this case
        var AP = [];
        return { 
            //copy map and indexOf from the Array prototype
            map: AP.map,
            indexOf: AP.indexOf, 

            //and add a custom toString and clone-method to the prototype
            toString: function(){
                return "UPCA[ "+AP.join.call(this, ", ")+" ]";
            },
            clone: function(){
                return _barcode.UPCA.apply(null, this);
            } 
        };
    },

    //OR
    "QRCode": {
        //or simply define an object that contains the properties/methods 
        //that should be added to the proto of QRCode
        //again configurable and writable but not enumerable

        substr: String.prototype.substr,
        substring: String.prototype.substring,
        charAt: String.prototype.charAt,
        charCodeAt: String.prototype.charCodeAt
    }
});
//mixin-functions and objects can be mixed
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) for this. This example uses Typescript, but the concept would be similar for Javascript just without the type safety.

```
interface UPCA {
    kind: "UPCA";
    numberSystem: number;
    manufacturer: number;
    item: number;
    checkDigit: number;
}

interface QRCode {
    kind: "QRCode";
    data: string;
}

interface Other {
    kind: "Other";
}

type Barcode = UPCA | QRCode | Other;
```

You can then switch over a value of `Barcode` and access the associated values after checking the discriminate.

```
function printBarcode(barcode: Barcode) {
  switch (barcode.kind) {
    case "UPCA":
      console.log(`UPCA: ${barcode.numberSystem}-${barcode.manufacturer}`);
      break;
    case "QRCode":
      console.log(`QRCode: ${barcode.data}`);
      break;
    case "Other":
      console.log("Other barcode");
      break;
  } 
}
```