# How to implement Swift-style enum with associated values in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, swift, typescript, enums

What would be the most straightforward way of implementing Swift-style enums with associated values in Typescript? Is it possible?

Within enums with associated values, I'm looking for the specific case of `indirect enum` with associated values that can work with ASTs — see example below:

```
indirect enum Node {
    case op(Node, Node)
    case value(Double)
}
```

I found an answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106034/how-to-implement-swift-like-enums-with-associated-values-in-javascript) but it's about Javascript support rather than Typescript support. I don't think this is a duplicate of that question; there may be some solutions that work in TypeScript but not in JavaScript.

Comment: I would like to add an answer to this question, which does not work in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Never mind; posted it on [How do you emulate ADTs and pattern matching in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034017/how-do-you-emulate-adts-and-pattern-matching-in-typescript/).